# Azure Mobile App Service not picking up routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, azure-mobile-services

I have a project which I created via File > New > Project > Azure Mobile App

I've added routes to my `HttpConfiguration` in the `ConfifgureMobileApp()` method.

The code looks like this. Not in particular the line `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(...)`.

```
    private static void ConfigureMobileApp(IAppBuilder app, ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        builder.RegisterModule(new WebApiModule(config));
        var container = builder.Build();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        //For more information on Web API tracing, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=620686 
        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        config.Filters.Add(new CultureThreadingAttribute());
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{culture}/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        new MobileAppConfiguration()
            .AddTablesWithEntityFramework()
            .MapApiControllers()
            .ApplyTo(config);
        MobileAppSettingsDictionary settings = config.GetMobileAppSettingsProvider().GetMobileAppSettings();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.HostName))
        {
            // This middleware is intended to be used locally for debugging. By default, HostName will
            // only have a value when running in an App Service application.
            app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions
            {
                SigningKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"],
                ValidAudiences = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"] },
                ValidIssuers = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"] },
                TokenHandler = config.GetAppServiceTokenHandler()
            });
        }

        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
    }
```

But this route is not getting picked up. In my middleware, I've taken the {System.Web.Routing.RouteData} object from the `OwinContext.Environment` dictionary, and it contains no routes.

I am using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk, and in particular, I'm following the advice of that article by mapping the route before making the call to `ApplyTo(config)`.

Also, my action filter `CultureThreadingAttribute`, which changes the locale of the thread based on the `culture` coming in from the route, is failing to get picked up.

I suspect that there are multiple `HttpConfiguration` objects running around in my app. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The route for your culture and the route for MobileApps APIs are conflicting with one another likely.  Debugging the route handler will confirm it.  Set a breakpoint and take a look at the route table as a call comes in.

There is nothing magical about the [MobileAppController] attribute - it just enforces the ZUMO-API-VERSION.  You can remove the .MapApiControllers() element and use regular ASP.NET MVC routing for your API controllers.  This will simplify your API route definitions.

Comment: Thanks Adrian.

I added a NuGet reference to Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost, and replaced the contents of `ConfigureMobileApp` with
`GlobalConfiguration.Configure(c => Configure(app, builder, c))`. That meant that the route was picked up, and my RouteValueDictionary now contains the correct values (culture = "en-GB", controller = "Provider", id = {}). But the controller is not even being instantiated.

Comment: I have to be honest: I can't wait until all of this goes to .NET Core.

Comment: At least the problem is no longer Mobile Apps, but a straight MVC issue :-)

Comment: I'll update my post, and maybe add an answer, once I've worked out how to fix this.

Comment: I think this was a PIBKAC. I added a handler, and it turned out I needed a binding redirect on my server side. I don't think this is relevant to most people, so I may delete this question shortly.